# Diff / Delta script: ideas on streamlining it?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, dynamic-sql, delta

I'm pulling data from a remote DB into a local MS SQL Server DB, the criteria being whether the PK is higher than I have in my data warehouse or whether the edit date is within a range that I provide with an argument.  That works super fast so I am happy with it.  However, when I attempt to sync this delta table into my data warehouse it takes quite a long time.

Here's my SPROC:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Sync_Delta_Table] 
@tableName varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @sql as varchar(4000)

-- Delete rows in MIRROR database where ID exists in the DELTA database
SET @sql = 'Delete from [SERVER-WHS].[MIRROR].[dbo].[' + @tableName
+ '] Where [ID] in (Select [ID] from [SERVER-DELTA].[DELTAS].[dbo].[' + @tableName + '])'
EXEC(@sql)

-- Insert all deltas
SET @sql = 'Insert Into [SERVER-WHS].[MIRROR].[dbo].[' + @tableName
+ '] Select * from [SERVER-DELTA].[DELTAS].[dbo].[' + @tableName + ']'
EXEC(@sql)

END
```

It works, but I think it takes way too long.  For example: inserting 3590 records from the DELTA table into the MIRROR table containing 3,600,761 took over 25 minutes.

Can anyone give me a hint on how I can make this job easier on SSMS?  I'm using 2008 R2, btw.

Thanks again!

Nate

Comment: Over 25 minutes...That's just for one table, right?  Between the DELETEs and the INSERTs, which is taking longer?

Comment: I believe the DELETE is the time consuming portion.  When I do the first run of the day it takes half the time, I believe this is because there is little or nothing to delete. This will take a few days to evaluate since I can only do a "daily first run" once a day by definition (:P) .  Will report back when I complete this analysis.

Comment: Some interesting suggestions have been included in the answers so far...Just don't be the victim of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  With that in mind, I would run a trace. Find out exactly which parts (tsql statements) of the stored proc are slow.  Then begin searching for the solution.

Comment: Well, I am fully focused on addressing the issue, which is that I believe the query is slower than it needs to be.  It is contingent upon me to detail my efforts to resolving this perceived issue, according to Stack Exchange's pre-question blurb, so I am providing as much as possible so that any help provided isn't something I've already tried.  Of course it might expose my noobery, but such are the risks we run.

Comment: It's definitely the DELETE portion.  The DELETE for each synced table runs about 5-6 minutes and the INSERT part takes about 30 seconds.  Based on this conversation I'm looking at doing something like this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297355/change-a-primary-key-from-nonclustered-to-clustered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is likely the time required to do a table scan on the 3,600,761 to see if the new records are unique.

First of all, let's confirm that the primary key (ID) on the target table is the clustered index and increasing.

```
SELECT s.name, o.name, i.name, i.type_desc, ic.key_ordinal, c.name
FROM sys.objects o
JOIN sys.columns c ON (c.object_id = o.object_id)
JOIN sys.schemas s ON (s.schema_id = o.schema_id)
JOIN sys.indexes i ON (i.object_id = o.object_id) 
JOIN sys.index_columns ic ON (ic.object_id = i.object_id AND ic.index_id = i.index_id AND ic.column_id = c.column_id)
WHERE o.name = '[table_name]'
```

If the index is not an ascending integer, it is possible that the inserts are causing lots of page splits.

Second, what other objects does that insert affect.  Are there triggers, materialized views, or non-clustered indexes?

Third, do you have

My suggestion would be to stage the data on the mirror server in a local table.  It can be as simple as as:

```
SET @sql = 'SELECT INTO * [MIRROR].[dbo].[' + @tableName + '_Staging] from [SERVER-DELTA].[DELTAS].[dbo].[' + @tableName + ']'
EXEC(@sql)
```

After that add a clustered primary key to the table.

```
SET @sql = 'ALTER TABLE [MIRROR].[dbo].[' + @tableName + '_Staging] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_' + @tableName + ']  PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id ASC)'
EXEC(@sql)
```

At this point, try inserting the data into the real table.  The optimizer should be much more helpful this time.

Comment: 1: The query provided returned no results.  My assumption is that this means despite having a primary key that this table is not indexed.  2: No other objects that I am aware of.  There are dependent views, but my assumption was that these aren't a burden until they are run.  3:  I'll give that a try.

Comment: So I talked with my sysadmin / IT Director and he said that the PK in the tables we have should cause it to be indexed, it makes me curious: would adding a second Clustered PK necessarily help?

Comment: Yes, a primary key causes it to be indexed, but the index is not necessarily clustered.  You can only have one clustered index per table.

Comment: This wasn't the exact answer I was looking for, but you got me very close to what I needed.  In many cases I had 2 PK so I went with `SET sql = 'ALTER TABLE [' + tableName + '] 
DROP CONSTRAINT [' + tableName + '_PK]

ALTER TABLE [' + tableName + '] 
ADD  CONSTRAINT [' + tableName + '_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (' + PK1 + ' ASC, ' + PK1 + ' ASC)'`  I now have 10 tables syncing in under 15 minutes!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Change the delete portion to:

```
SET @sql = 'Delete tbl1 from [SERVER-WHS].[MIRROR].[dbo].[' + @tableName
+ '] tbl1 inner join [SERVER-DELTA].[DELTAS].[dbo].[' + @tableName + '] tbl2 on tbl1.[ID] = tbl2.[ID]'
```

In future use INNER JOIN instead of IN with Sub Query.

Comment: I tried your suggestion with a similar data set, they difference was less than a minute with the Join solution clocking in a little slower.  Thanks for your input, though!

Comment: This ultimately worked out being helpful input because in most cases the tables had 2 PK and I needed to join on multiple criteria.  Thanks!